# curselection() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
lbox = Listbox
def Show():
    Selected=lbox.get(lbox.curselection())
    with open("pass.json","r+") as jfile:
            try:
                data=json.load(jfile)
                for i in data['Details']:
                    if Selected==i["Site"]:
                        password_text.set(i["Password"])
                        uname_text.set(i["Username"])
            except JSONDecodeError:
                pass
```

I wanted to use curselection() but curselection() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' is coming all the time
lbox was declared in another function which is given below

```py
def Show_fun():
    newWindow=Toplevel(window)
    newWindow.title("Show your stuff")
    newWindow.geometry("600x400")
    Label(newWindow,text="Show passwords").grid(row=0,column=1,pady=10)

    Label(newWindow,text="Site name : ").grid(row=1,pady=10)
    lbox=Listbox(newWindow)
    lbox.grid(row=1,column=2) 
sites=[]
    with open("pass.json","r+") as jfile:
            try:
                data=json.load(jfile)
                for i in data['Details']:
                    sites.append(i["Site"])

            except JSONDecodeError:
                pass
    
    lbox.config(height=lbox.size())

    for i in sites:
        lbox.insert(lbox.size(),i)
    
    #site_entry = Entry(newWindow,textvariable = site_text,width=20,state=DISABLED).grid(row=1,column=2) 

    Label(newWindow,text="Username : ").grid(row=2,pady=10)
    uname_entry=Entry(newWindow,textvariable=uname_text,state=DISABLED).grid(row=2,column=2)

    Label(newWindow,text="Password : ").grid(row=3,pady=10)
    pasword_entry=Entry(newWindow,textvariable=password_text,width=20,state=DISABLED).grid(row=3,column=2)
    Button(newWindow,text="Show",command=Show,fg="#00FF00",bg="black",pady=10).grid(row=4,column=1)
```

I saw many YT vids . ListBox was working globally but in my its not working globally

EDIT: after giving parenthesis to ListBox() New error arises

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1895, in __call__  
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:/Python files/cybersecurity/password manager/password_test.py", line 24, in Show
    Selected=lbox.get(lbox.curselection())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\l`enter code here`ib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3190, in get       
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', first)
_tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number
```

Comment: Can you add the exact error message you are getting in this post?

Comment: curselection() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: please add the full error message starting from the word "Traceback" in your question (use [edit]ing), also provide a [mre] and delete your comment

Comment: You have created two instances of `Listbox`: one on the global scope (after you added `()`) and it is hidden, second inside `Show_fun()`.  `lbox` inside `Show()` is referencing the global one which has nothing inside it and so `lbox.curselection()` will always return empty tuple.  Exception raised when empty tuple is passed to `lbox.get()`.

Comment: @acw1668 So sir any idea how could I reference the lbox which is inside showfun(). Only thing i can think of is defining Show() inside Show_fun() which does feel wrong but for the button to work Show() should be a function

Comment: Pass `lbox` as an argument of `Show()`: `def Show(lbox)` and `command=lambda: Show(lbox)`.

Answer (score 2):

The error message simply means that the method was not invoked on the **object** but on the class instead. In the first code snippet, you didn't seem to instantiate a `ListBox` object.

You must change the line

```
lbox = Listbox
```

to something like:

```
# Tkinter window object
window = Tk()

# Create ListBox object and bind to the Tkinter window
lbox = Listbox(window)
```

In the above snippet, an instance of `ListBox` is created on which the method `curselection()` could be called. Give more emphasis to the argument passed to `ListBox`. The `window` variable used above is an instance of the `Tk` class which essentially constructs the Tkinter window. Without this argument, the listbox widget won't know which window it must bind to.

Comment: i  instantiate in 2nd function ,  also gave parenthesis to ListBox() new error came its edited above

Comment: @WarHawk121 but it is not global there, also you should provide a [mre], new error is because `.curselection()` may return an empty tuple

Comment: @WarHawk121 Based on the error traceback in the post, the error is caused in the first snippet inside the `Show()` function.